# Getting loop to work through json javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I can't get this code to loop through the json it grabs the first data and then stops.
I've simplified it to kind of start for scratch but not sure what stupid thing I'm missing. Thinking its a simple 'hey Dumas do this'
in example I've pulled out the meta, ref, and jquery stuff

````
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>SN</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        const jsonData2 = {
            "result": [{
                "data": [{
                    "user": "admin",
                    "name": "Frank Admin",
                    "OS": "Windows",
                    "sn": "yadayoda123"
                }, {
                    "user": "root",
                    "name": "john root",
                    "OS": "OS/2",
                    "sn": "123-A"
                }]
            }]
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        buildTable(jsonData2)
        function buildTable(data2) {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            }
            Object.entries(data2.result).forEach(([name, details]) => {
                console.log("gotname?", details.data[i]);
                console.log("whats i", i);
                var row = `<tr>
              <td>${details.data[i].name}</td>
              <td>${details.data[i].user}</td>
              <td>${details.data[i].os}</td> 
              <td>${details.data[i].sn}</td> 
            </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html```
````

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced } in loop and limit loop with data2.result.length

```html
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>SN</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        const jsonData2 = {
            "result": [{
                "data": [{
                    "user": "admin",
                    "name": "Frank Admin",
                    "OS": "Windows",
                    "sn": "yadayoda123"
                }, {
                    "user": "root",
                    "name": "john root",
                    "OS": "OS/2",
                    "sn": "123-A"
                }]
            }]
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        buildTable(jsonData2)
        function buildTable(data2) {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            for (var i = 0; i <= data2.result.length; i++) {
            Object.entries(data2.result).forEach(([name, details]) => {
                //console.log("gotname?", details.data[i]);
                //console.log("whats i", i);
                var row = `<tr>
              <td>${details.data[i].name}</td>
              <td>${details.data[i].user}</td>
              <td>${details.data[i].OS}</td> 
              <td>${details.data[i].sn}</td> 
            </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
            });
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Dude!  Thank You! Many Tylenol were saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it in a simple way. Also, google about indentation and try to give your code structure that you'll understand

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");

const jsonData2 = {
            "result": [{
                "data": [{
                    "user": "admin",
                    "name": "Frank Admin",
                    "OS": "Windows",
                    "sn": "yadayoda123"
                }, {
                    "user": "root",
                    "name": "john root",
                    "OS": "OS/2",
                    "sn": "123-A"
                }]
            }]
        }
        
  let row = ``;
  jsonData2.result[0].data.forEach(object => {
    row = `<tr>
              <td>${object.name}</td>
              <td>${object.user}</td>
              <td>${object.os}</td> 
              <td>${object.sn}</td> 
            </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
 })
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>SN</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```